# Which is the best container for finding and inserting?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, containers

I need to insert many items in a container. If an item is already in the container, don't insert. I need to do it multiple times. The items need not to be sorted.
I am confused whether to use set(binary tree) or unordered_set(hash table). Since my items are going to be unique, will hash table be less effective?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason not to, just use a `std::vector` (or `std::array`).

Comment: Just use `unordered_set`

Answer (score 3):

Since you say

- you don't need the items to be ordered
- you don't want duplicates

the most logical container is a set.

There is no need to use `std::set` because it tries to preserve order (which you say you don't need).

`std::unordered_set` is a good choice because it is fast for insertions and checking if an item is in the set.

Answer (score 1):

unordered_set is better that set since you don't need the elements to be sorted. For find and insert algo unordered_set time complexity is O(1) ; set is O(log(N)). So in the case should prefer to use unordered_set.

Answer (score -1):

Use [sdt::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/)

```
struct data_t
{
    int value;
    data_t(): value(-1){} // default value should be invalid for any other values
};

std::map<std::string, data_t> datamap;
int yourvalue = 100;
int value = datamap["item"].value;

if (value == -1) {
    datamap["item"].value = yourvalue;
} else {
    //Already exists
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention any associativity being needed, so a `map` seems overkill. Also I don't think it's a good idea to recommend using a "default-value" as a sentinel check. C++ has better facilities for representing an unset value (such as `std::optional`), and sentinel values make it really easy for a "garbage-in, garbage-out" scenario where `.value` may have been forgotten to be checked